# adding together same dataframes of a nested list in r

Tags: r, nested-lists, addition

I am trying to sum many dataframes of a nested list (kind of matrix sum; same cell in one data frame with same cell another...).
The list has three levels and it goes as follows:

-  first level is representet by numbers (eg. 1 to 5)

- second levels includes months (jan to dec)

- third level conissts of a data frame (31 rows and 31 columns).

So what I wanted to do is to get a new data frame that has the sum of the same month for numbers 1 to 5.

I get the wanted result if I sum the dataframes like:

```
month <- listname[[1]][["month"]] + listname[[2]][["month"]] + listname[[3]][["month"]] + listname[[4]][["month"]]....
```

Because I have to automate this proces for numbers 1 to N I cannot use the addition used in above example.

I hope you good people of this comunity can help me find a solution.

Gregor

Comment: Can you share sample data?

Answer (score 0):

See if below works. Result should be a list with desired result for each month

```
# change months to in format as in your data.
months <- c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec")

lapply(months, function(month){
  Reduce(`+`,
         lapply(listname, function(x) {
           x[[month]]
         }))
})
```